# how to read an excel file using node.js

Tags: node.js, excel, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to read an **excel file** present in **S3** using **node.js** integrated with **lambda**. I mean the code should **interact** with excel file and display the output.
Please help me in this issue.